# How to create Multiple Uses in Perforce

Tags: perforce

Is there a way we (superAdmin) can create multiple users with their email addresses in Perforce, either using the command line or using scipt (python or shell)?

Shell script would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `p4 user -o` command to output a user spec, and `p4 user -i` (with the `-f` flag if your server is configured to require superuser permission to create new users) to save it.

The email address defaults to `user@client` so an easy way to set the email address without actually editing the form is to just specify the email domain as the client name (you don't need to create an actual client spec) via the `-c` global flag, e.g.:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -c gmail.com user -o fred
# A Perforce User Specification.
#
#  User:        The user's user name.
#  Type:        Either 'service', 'operator', or 'standard'.
#               Default: 'standard'. Read only.
#  Email:       The user's email address; for email review.
#  Update:      The date this specification was last modified.
#  Access:      The date this user was last active.  Read only.
#  FullName:    The user's real name.
#  JobView:     Selects jobs for inclusion during changelist creation.
#  Password:    If set, user must have matching $P4PASSWD on client.
#  AuthMethod:  'perforce' if using standard authentication or 'ldap' if
#               this user should use native LDAP authentication.
#  Reviews:     Listing of depot files to be reviewed by user.

User:   fred

Email:  fred@gmail.com

FullName:       fred
```

Piping this output to `p4 user -i -f` saves the user spec:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -c gmail.com user -o fred | p4 user -i -f
User fred saved.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 users fred
fred <fred@gmail.com> (fred) accessed 2022/09/21
```

If you need to edit the actual form (e.g. to set the `FullName`), you can always use text editing tools like `sed`, but an easier option is to use the built-in `--field` global flag, which lets you set individual spec fields in command output:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 --field Email=fred@bedrock.gov --field "FullName=Fred Flintstone" user -o fred
User:   fred

Type:   standard

Email:  fred@bedrock.gov

Update: 2022/09/21 08:50:34

Access: 2022/09/21 08:50:34

FullName:       Fred Flintstone

AuthMethod:     perforce
```

Again, to actually save the user spec you just need to pipe this to `p4 user -i`:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 --field Email=fred@bedrock.gov --field "FullName=Fred Flintstone" user -o fred | p4 user -if
User fred saved.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 users fred
fred <fred@bedrock.gov> (Fred Flintstone) accessed 2022/09/21
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Samwise, it is greatly appreciated. However, how can the same user be added to the P4 group using the same command?

Comment: Use `p4 group` to edit groups, just like you use `p4 user` to edit users.

Comment: Is it possible to pipe `p4 group <group_name> --field "Users=<user.name>"` with the command mentioned above `p4 --field Email=fred@bedrock.gov --field "FullName=Fred Flintstone" user -o fred | p4 user -if` ?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible.  When you post these questions you should just say up front what it is you're trying to do instead of asking the first half of the question up front and then asking the second half in a comment.  :)

Comment: @Samwise Where did you find "built-in --field global flag"? I've never seen that.

Comment: It's in `p4 help undoc`.